# Generate several pdf on a page with FPDI in PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to display a pdf but page by page (separated pages). The thing is that once I generate a page with FPDI, I have 4 options:

1. download generated pdf
2. display it directly to the browser (streaming like)
3. generate an string that represents the pdf
4. save as a file

What I would like to do is take option 3, put every string generated for each page and display it in different divs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I gave up with FPDI + PHP solution and I replaced by PDF.js + turn.js, based on https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/82